# Custom Rewrite rule to captured post (rewrite rule to rewrite rule)

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, mod-rewrite

I couldn't come up with a better question-title; Sorry! The example will clarify things quickly.

My rule:

`add_rewrite_rule("^podcast/(.*)/time/([\d|\:]+)", "/podcast/$1/?time=$2", "top");`

In words: Podcasts jump to the a specific time when the get-var `time` is given. This link needs to be more user-friendly, like `http://some.blog/podcast/crazy-pod-title/time/20:10`

The regex works great. When I direct this rule to "test.php?title=$1&time=$2" – everything seems to work as expected.

But redirecting to a wordpress-permalink is not working.
So, how do I get `/podcast/xxx/time/mm:ss` directed to `/podcast/xxx/?time=mm:ss`?

Thank you!

BONUS-QUESTION: Looking at the .htaccess on the server I realized: wordpress can't write permalinks in .htaccess for dynamic content. How does wordpress handle the URLs? I only know the .htaccess-way